# How to get alpha value for specific recyclerview item from preferences

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, sharedpreferences

i have a recyclerview where some items(strings) are with alpha value 1.0F and some others with 0.2F. I try to save each alpha value on shared preferences so as to retrieve the same alpha values for the same items but what i get is either all items with 1.0F, or all items with 0.2F alpha.
On the adapter the onBindViewHolder method looks like this:

```
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(
            "shared preferences",
            AppCompatActivity.MODE_PRIVATE
        )

        alphaValue = sharedPreferences!!.getFloat("alphaValue", alphaValue)

        val current = list[position]

        holder.product.text = current.product

        holder.itemView.alpha = alphaValue

        holder.product.setOnClickListener {
            if (holder.itemView.alpha.equals(1.0F)) {
                holder.itemView.alpha = 0.2F
                alphaValue = 0.2F
                editor = sharedPreferences!!.edit()
                editor.putFloat("alphaValue", alphaValue)
                editor.commit()
                editor.apply()


            } else {
                holder.itemView.alpha = 1.0F
                alphaValue = 1.0F
                editor = sharedPreferences!!.edit()
                editor.putFloat("alphaValue", alphaValue)
                editor.commit()
                editor.apply()
            }
        }
    }
```